# How to retrieve part of body returned in JSON format inside node Js

Tags: json, request, nodes

i am new with node js, my problem that i used code to subscribe for event inside node js and it returns me body with JSON format. I want to take only part of this body (the second parts),
This is the returned body,
{ id: 'RandomNumber',
  type: 'event',
  payload: { timeStamp: '2018-02-25T12:59:55.740' } }

I want only to retrieve the part of seconds from the timer in this body,
after search i used this code inside the callback function
var sec = body.getSeconds;
    console.log(sec);
but it didn't make any difference and the whole body is printed not part of it

Comment: can you show us your code, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to get seconds from body itself not from timeStamp.
Try var sec = body.payload.timeStamp.getSeconds; console.log(sec);